# stored procedure 'IF' statement + 'UPDATE' or 'INSERT' based on null fields

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm a casual user as far as DBs are concerned. I've been tasked to create procedures where they are basically going to be doing a very rudimentary autosave feature.

I've created stored procedures before but none with the restraint of having to check for NULL entries and using IF statements to determine if an UPDATE needs to be done or a new INSERT.

DB: MySQL
Editor: MYSQL WorkBench

Here's my procedure:

---

```
CREATE DEFINER=`appuser`@`15.15.15.%` PROCEDURE `test `(
  id varchar(45),
  q01 varchar(2),
  a01 varchar(45),
  …
  q06 varchar(2),
  a06 varchar(45)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _nullCheck VARCHAR(25);

    SET _ nullCheck  = (SELECT statement to check for null entries));
    IF (_nullCheck) THEN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE statement
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT statement
        END;
END;
```

In my MySQL Workbench, its telling me that this 'END' is missing an 'IF'

---

I built my stored procedure after looking at other threads about IFs and stored procedures and this is what I came up with.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or help.

EDIT CORRECTION:

---

```
CREATE DEFINER=`appuser`@`15.15.15.%` PROCEDURE `test `(
  id varchar(45),
  q01 varchar(2),
  a01 varchar(45),
  …
  q06 varchar(2),
  a06 varchar(45)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _nullCheck VARCHAR(25);

    SET _ nullCheck  = (SELECT statement to check for null entries));

    IF (_nullCheck) THEN
            UPDATE statement
    ELSE
            INSERT statement
    END IF;
END
```

---

Comment: Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: Missing `END IF;`.

Comment: ok I figured out my error in my pseudo code for stored procedure, now my issue is my conditional isn't firing at all now.

Comment: editing code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: (pseudo-code of procedure, doesn't compile)

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE DEFINER=`appuser`@`15.15.15.%` PROCEDURE `test` (
    ->   id varchar(45),
    ->   q01 varchar(2),
    ->   a01 varchar(45),
    ->   …
    ->   q06 varchar(2),
    ->   a06 varchar(45)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE _nullCheck VARCHAR(25);
    ->   SET _ nullCheck  = (SELECT statement to check for null entries));
    ->   IF (_nullCheck) THEN
    ->     BEGIN
    ->       UPDATE statement
    ->     END;
    ->   ELSE
    ->     BEGIN
    ->       INSERT statement
    ->     END;
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

**UPDATE**

```sql
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `test` (
    ->   id varchar(45),
    ->   q01 varchar(2),
    ->   a01 varchar(45),
    ->   q06 varchar(2),
    ->   a06 varchar(45)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `_nullCheck` VARCHAR(25);
    ->   SET `_nullCheck` := (SELECT 'TRUE');
    ->   IF (`_nullCheck` = 'TRUE') THEN
    ->     SELECT 'UPDATE';
    ->   ELSE
    ->     SELECT 'INSERT';
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `test`(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
+--------+
| UPDATE |
+--------+
| UPDATE |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: now my issue is my conditional isnt firing off now when I do a procedure call to it.

the insert statement works by itself and the update statement works by itself, but put into the conditional neither is firing.

Even when I put a true condition into it (5>4).

and its not giving me any errors when I saved my corrected store procedure and its not erroring out on the call itself. 

I'm not sure how to trouble shoot why its not firing like it should